# PROBLEM : when Update my system (in directory).

Tags: sudo, dpkg, directory

When I type `sudo apt-get update` in terminal that shows error like this

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure another process is not active such as Software Center, Synaptic Package Manager or Update Manager?

Comment: restart your PC and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If software update is running you will not be able to perform sudo apt-get update from terminal. Ubuntu allows only one instance of process to run such as apt-get update, package manager, update manager or software center because those require administrative rights. You should first wait for your update manager to finish it's job or simply close it. Then maybe restart your computer.